# How do I make ansible install nginx from a bitbucket repo to a target host?

Tags: nginx, ansible, bitbucket

How do I get an installer from a remote `bitbucket` repository then do an install on a target host?

on a local network (no internet connection), I have :

- `Ansible` is on a `Rhel 7` virtual machine
- `bitbucket` is on a `Windows Server 2016` virtual machine
- the target host is on another `Rhel 7 vm`

all of them can connect to each other via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git module to download the installer from git to the controller machine. The flow would be like below:

```
controller machine:

  git: copy the installer using ssh protocol

once the installer is on your local you can copy from controller to target 

copy: from controller machine to target server

install: nginx
```

target server

bitbucket --> repo